# Why is z-index not working on these two elements?

Tags: css, z-index

You can see my issue here:

http://pmind.com/staging/123.html

I've tested this in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera so I know it's not just an Internet Explorer wonky bug.

In the top right of the content, there are two text links, that are being hidden under the graphic. The `<div>` that contains the text links comes further down in the page, and my understanding was that that alone would make the z-index of the links such that they would be on top. But because that didn't do it, I set the z-index of the `<div>` containing the text links manually, which still didn't fix the problem.

One partial solution I found was to set the z-index of everything on the page but the `<div>` to -1. This however broke the roll-over functionality of the navigation items. I hate to ask something like this, and then it be some extremely simple issue I've just overlooked, but I'm at my wit's end.

Comment: The example link is no longer active, but the reason for my problem was I didn't realize elements in the page that had a position:relative or :absolute live in a different stacking order than things that don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding "position: relative;" to #top_links brings them to the front in Firefox. I haven't tested this in other browsers.

Comment: You're welcome, Michael. If you think, an answer solves your problem, you can mark it as correct by clicking the check mark to the left of it.